# What number is missing in the pentagon?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

[image: pentagon]

What number is missing in the pentagon?

Puzzle from: https://www.rondogo.sk/hra/

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: It looks like that's a [competition](https://www.rondogo.sk/stranky/terms) -is it ongoing?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> 22

> The middle number is sum of individual digits of the numbers in other pentagons