# What is the Result of this icon Equation?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image]from:https://www.rondogo.sk/hra
I have problem with heart :)
A) 19
B) 20
C) 21
D) 22

Comment: Is it true that the answer is really 21?

Comment: Is there a better quality image? The third woman on the first equation looks different to the others (strange looking shape on her dress) and I can't tell whether it is intentional or not.

Comment: video: https://youtu.be/aF7iJy40r3c?t=107

Comment: The answer being 21 can be entirely explained by looking more closely at the dress of the girl in the bottom picture. Those aren't circular buttons...

Comment: Repeating what I said [before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114308/what-number-is-missing-in-the-pentagon#comment319921_114308): it sure looks like that's a [competition](https://www.rondogo.sk/stranky/terms)

Comment: The value of boy+ his heart in his chest is 3. But in the last line the boy might took his heart out and keep it in his hand! but the next heart means love. So A)19 also makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> 21

We can work out the values of each icon (GIRL, BOY, HEART) by solving the first 3 equations:

> Equation 1 yields GIRL = 5.
>
>  Using this, Equation 2 yields BOY = 3.
>
>  Using this also, Equation 3 yields HEART = 2.

The trick to solving the final equation is the same as for all internet puzzles of this type - you have to *notice the additional icons hidden in the image*. In this case:

> The girl's buttons have been replaced with heart icons. Thus the final answer is:
>
>  (BOY + HEART) + (BOY + HEART + GIRL + 3*HEART)
>
>  i.e. (3 + 2) + (3 + 2 + 5 + 3*2), which equals **21** as required.

Answer (score 1):

> If handholding represents concatenation and the raised heart represents exponentiation then the final expression would be 32 + 35^2 = 1257, but this might be wrong.

Comment: I like your solution (!) but clearly this kind of problem has multiple interpretations and the "correct" interpretation depends on an understanding of the accepted, normal conventions for the puzzle type which, in this case, are explained by @Stiv.

Answer (score 0):

357 or 36 or 51

> Eq. 1: girl = 5
>
>  Eq. 2: boy = 3
>
>  Eq. 3: heart = 2
>
>
>  If you combine digits into numbers:
>  $32 + 325 = 357$
>
>  If you take this as multiplication:
>  $3 * 2 + 3 * 2 * 5 = 36$
>
>  If you treat the heart between characters as a power and the rest as multiplication:
>  $3 * 2 + 3 ^ 2 * 5 = 51$